# Can I iterate objects from my Django model over a modified HTMLCalendar()?

Tags: python, django

This code will only retrieve a single object from the database, rather than iterate them throughout the calendar on their applicable date.

cal.py

```
from www.wednesday.models import Event
import calendar

class EventCal(calendar.HTMLCalendar):         
    def formatday(self, day, weekday):     
        if day == 0:
            return '<td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>' # Day outside month
        if day == int(event.dateDay.day):
            return '<td class="%s">%d</p><a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\">%s</a></td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, event.linkURL, event.restaurant)
        else:
            return '<td class="%s">%d</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day)

events = Event.objects.all()
for event in events:
    class rendCal():
        c = EventCal(calendar.SUNDAY)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from www.wednesday.models import Event
from www.wednesday.cal import *
import datetime as dt

Months = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

now = dt.datetime.now()
mon = now.month

def calend(request):
    cal = rendCal.c.formatmonth(now.year, now.month)
    events = Event.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('cal.html', {'calendar': cal,
                                           'title': 'Win-Win Wednesday Calendar for %s' % Months[int(mon)]})
```

cal.html

```
# ...
<div id='calendar'>

<div>
</div>
{% block main %}
{{ calendar|safe }}
{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "It iterate the whole calendar twice (I've put 2 events into the database),"?  What does this mean?  What iterates over the calendar twice?  "but only prints the calendar modifications once"? Prints? Where?  How?  There are no print statement?    Also, you haven't provided the code for `formatmonth`, so it's quite hard to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Fair enough.  The whole calendar is rendered twice, but it only pulls the most recent event from my Event model.  I've tried pulling the objects directly too, and it works for the first object and then loops the whole calendar that way.  I know, at least with this version of the code, the error is in a. the for loop in the template, and b. the rendering of the calendar; I'm just not sure where the for loop needs to be to iterate all events into the calendar.

Comment: Don't add long, hard-to-read comments.  Please **update** the question to be complete.

Comment: "This version only returns the most recent Event object"?  What?  What is your question, exactly?  Can you remove the "update:" business and just ask the question you would like answered?  Focus -- please -- on specific questions we can actually answer.  We can't guess what problem you're having if you keep changing things.  Your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your question is murky.

> And, it's printing the django tag {{ event.restaurant }} rather than the data from the model.

That's because `formatday()` returns the string `"{{ event.restaurant }}"`.

The template rendering inserts that string into the template.

The template rendering doesn't look at the data it inserts to see if the data is more template code.  It just inserts data into the template.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of a shot in the dark.  The closest I've gotten was without the for loop in the html template, and calling the objects directly in the calendar.  However, for some reason, it will only pull the first Event.  I know they need to be iterated over, I just haven't figured out where.